# VS code filename suggestions are not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

My problem here is after the config folder it's not auto-suggestion the remaining file names, but in config contains few files.

And another problem is when I try to click the config by using ctl+click its not navigating to that file also

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for the `VS Code` [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extension, **which allows for the autocompletion of filenames.**

> **Visual Studio Code plugin that autocompletes filenames:.**
>
>
> [image: gif]

[VS code extension store link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) 
[GitHub link](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense)

Comment: @lejiun Thanks and I have another problem too could not redirect to method or filename when clicking that method name, kindly help here pls

Comment: @tamilmani: Please open a new question for this other problem.

Comment: added the question in the above discription itself already.